# sequelize How to join between 2 table that have 1 common column

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I have 2 table , the first table hold tags that one user love them
[image]

and the second table shows tags of one post

[image]

I want to call a query that gets tags that this user loves them
and then return related posts to this tag **without duplicate**

Comment: Simply JOINing these tables will not accomplish that. You could concatenate the related postID to a single CSV string.

Comment: it solved by this command

FavUserTags.hasOne(PostHashtak, {
  foreignKey: 'hashtakId', // <--- one of the column of PostHashtak - SubTask: not a primary key here in my case; can be primary key also
  sourceKey: 'hashtakId', // <---  one of the column of FavUserTags - Task: not a primary key here in my case; can be a primary key also
});